# What is correct WIFI, WiFi or Wi-Fi?

Tags: discussion

I have seen a lot of edits from "toyota supra" where the user corrects WiFi, Wi-Fi and wifi to WIFI.

In my opinion the abbreviation from https://www.wi-fi.org/ and that is Wi-Fi or WiFi.

Comment: Please accept my apology.

Comment: Not needed! And I have accepted a lot of your edits and I appreciate your contributions.

Comment: Most of these edits are trivial, and should be rejected. All they do is push poor posts up the Queue. Frankly WHO CARES - it doesn't help understanding? Also changing raspberry to Raspberry etc adds absolutely no value - particularly on an ancient post that has been ignored for years.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.  I assume Mr/Ms Supra believes it is a normal acronym, which it is not, and perhaps too young to be familiar with hi-fi, which it alludes to.

I will try and contact this person, in the meantime you should of course reject or correct any edits which you think are incorrect.

Comment: I was just curious what to do, I just want us to work in harmony. So no appologies is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepted, You can reject it. Some people write an English word Wi-Fi or WIFI. Recently, about 20 years ago, I saw something on TV saying that what is HIFI or Hi-Fi? Hi-Fi is high fidelity, and HIFI is just a name. Some peoples can write like that WIFI. But they do not care. Please accept my apology.

Comment: I have English dictionary that I brought from Ontario, Canada

Comment: And I have english as second language so I am far from 100% fluent in english ;-) And no hard feelings, just get it out in the open and lets discuss it and work together as a team.

Comment: Hi-Fi is, as you say, derived from High Fidelity. Wi-Fi is derived from Hi-Fi, with a hyphen, **not** HiFi **nor** HIFI.